# Simple SparkR 1.6 Example

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I'm working on getting a simple sparkR example up and running and can't get it to work.  All I want to do is take a list, parallelize it, and run a function in SparkR.  I haven't been able to find a simple example that goes over the way to do this in spark 1.6 -- it seems there are many ways to do it but none of them seem to work.  I am trying to run this in the sparkR console:

```
fxntest<- function(i){
  m = matrix(runif(4000*4000),4000)
  return(system.time(m %*% m))
}

a<-c(1,1,1,1,1,3)
b<-as.list(a)

sdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, b)
testtimes <- lapply(sdf, fxntest)
testtimelist <- collect(testtimes)
testtimelist
```

This is the error I am getting when lapply is being called:

```
Error in as.list.default(X) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

What I am looking for is a very simple example that gets this working -- I have used pyspark a good amount but haven't been able to get this working with R.

Comment: The error appear to be in `lapply`. What is that doing? It isn't using `i` at all

Comment: I just want that function to run in parallel across different workers -- I know I am ignoring "i".

Answer (score 0):

[`createDataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/R/createDataFrame.html) has been renamed to `as.DataFrame` since `1.6`.

This correctly works to create a Spark DataFrame in R.

```
sdf <- as.DataFrame(sqlContext, list(1,1,1,1,1,3))
```

However, that that is not an R object. The built-in R [`lapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/lapply) works on regular lists, arrays, vectors, etc.

You gain nothing by running this in Spark. The computation you are performing is not parallelized across a cluster. The matrix multiplication is done on a single machine. And Spark libraries are not used at all.

Here is the working code, for example

```
fxntest<- function(i){
  m = matrix(runif(4000*4000),4000)
  return(system.time(m %*% m))
}

testtimes <- lapply(list(1,1,1,1,1,3), fxntest)
```

Note: `spark.lapply` was added in Spark 2.x if that is the function that you were trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I know it is not parallelized--that is what I am trying to do! I am trying to get something working like spark.lapply but for sparkR 1.6 but haven't been able to get anything working.  The idea is to run these matrix multiplications in parallel.